# I have installed Firebase Analytics in my iOS app, but it is not logging automatically

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have installed Firebase Analytics with Firebase SDK in my iOS app.
And we are able to measure events, event parameters, and user properties without any problems.

However, when I open a ViewController without any of these codes, events such as screen_view are not measured. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Do I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, screenviews are automatically tracked every screen transition. It is based on the distinct UIViewController or Activity for each screen in your app.

On Apple platforms, Firebase depends on method swizzling to automatically log screen views. SwiftUI apps must manually set screen names for views that should be logged via the FirebaseAnalyticsSwift module, or log screen views manually.